# \textwidth is not recognized, causes illegal unit error

Tags: r, knitr, markdown, textwidth

I switched computers, reinstalled R, and am now getting an "Illegal unit of measure" error when I run the following code. I've narrowed it down to the "\textwidth" portion - when I take that out it runs but does not give the desired affect. Any advice on how I can get \textwidth running again would be greatly appreciated!

```
---
title: "TestFile"
author: "Brian Hurler"
date: "12/15/2020"
output: pdf_document

header-includes:
  - \usepackage{subfigure}
---

{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::include_graphics
library(knitr)
library(remotes)
library(lubridate)
library(datavolley)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggalt)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(RGraphics)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggimage)
library(magick)
library(jpeg)
library(zoo)
library(readxl)

{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results = "asis", out.width= "900px", include=FALSE}

player_name <- c("Brian Hurley", "Justin Zhang", "Jon Fong", "Brian Hurley", "Justin Zhang", "Jon Fong", "Brian Hurley", "Justin Zhang", "Jon Fong")
matches <- data.frame(player_name)

scout_reception <- matches %>%
  group_by(player_name) %>%
  summarise(
    attempts = n())

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}[c][3.95in]{0.72\textwidth}

{r}
kable(scout_reception)

\end{minipage}
\hspace{-.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}[c][3.95in]

{r}
kable(scout_reception)

\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! It's possible that some people here know more about R, but for a lot more people including me, this question may be easier to answer/understand if you share the actual `.tex` file that is being compiled (generated by knitr or whatever the right thing is), so that the (La)TeX part of the question/problem can be isolated.

Comment: You forgot to specify a length for the second `minipage` construction. Add a length and compile again.

Comment: @Werner Hi, thanks! I get the same error when including {0.28\textwidth} on the second minipage. If I remove it from both minipages, the code runs.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Hi! Do I just paste the contents of the main tex file from my computer? I believe I am just using the standard tinytex, which was installed with R. Other than what's posted above, I haven't made any changes.

Comment: @VBtech I guess you put the above contents into a .Rmd file. Somewhere on your system, probably in the same directory as the .Rmd file or maybe somewhere else (the Knitr cache directory?) there will be a `.tex` file with probably the same name. *That* file is the one seen by TeX (some part of R, maybe knitr, generates that file and passes it to TeX). And if you paste that file here, it may be obvious what's wrong with it. Alternatively, you can ask this question on an R forum, as they may be able to notice errors in your R Markdown (I guess?) syntax.

Comment: The examples of R Markdown that I can find online (e.g. [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-2.html)) all have the R code in fenced code blocks, i.e. starting with something like `\`\`\`{r}` and ending with `\`\`\``. In the text shown above, you have R code and LaTeX code mixed with no such indication, and lines like `{r}` just right there on their own. Are you sure your file above is exactly correct in its syntax, i.e. that it ever worked? Also, doesn't the LaTeX code need to be marked up somehow, too?

Comment: (Deleted my previous comment.) The main issue is that this file is not in proper RMarkdown syntax: the embedded R and LaTeX code blocks should be marked as such, using backticks, so that they are not interpreted as Markdown. There is also a genuine LaTeX error, that @Werner pointed out above. Have posted this as an answer; please let us know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

### Background

If I understand correctly, the code posted in the question is the contents of an [R Markdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) file. This ([example](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-2.html)) is a Markdown file that can contain embedded code blocks in [R language](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=R_(programming_language)&oldid=994403679). The contents of those blocks will be executed as R code. Moreover, such a file can be exported (using [Knitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Knitr&oldid=986711859)), which (via Pandoc) invokes LaTeX to produce PDF output. Note that the developer of [Knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/) ([Yihui Xie](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Yihui_Xie&oldid=989212509)) is also a co-author of the book [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/).

The easiest way to get started appears to be via the [RStudio IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=RStudio&oldid=993096024):

- Install it on your computer, or create a new project at https://rstudio.cloud.
- Go to File → New File → R Markdown, and select PDF output
- Optionally, next to "Knit" click on the settings icon → Output options → Advanced, and check "Keep tex source file used to produce PDF". (This is equivalent to simply putting `keep_tex: yes` in the header, as below.)

With this `keep_tex` set, after Knitr generates (or attempts to generate) the PDF output, it will not delete the actual `.tex` file that it tried to compile. (This will be probably in the same directory as the `.Rmd` file, or in whatever directory is set as the Knitr cache directory.) For questions on this site, it may be better to share that `.tex` file, so that the LaTeX part can be isolated, and RMarkdown syntax errors can be ruled out.

#### Answer to this question

The [file shown in the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/575216/1) has some syntax errors, and needs the following changes to work correctly:

- The R code blocks must be marked with fenced code blocks starting with three backticks before the `{r…`.
- The LaTeX code blocks must be similarly marked, with three backticks followed by `{=latex}` (see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html)).
- The `datavolley` library is not on CRAN (which is R's analogue of CTAN). Maybe it's from [here](https://github.com/openvolley/datavolley), but anyway it seems not to be necessary for this example so I just commented it out.
- Finally (this is the only *actual* LaTeX error), as Werner pointed out in the comments, the second `minipage` above needs a length specification (say the same `{0.72\textwidth}` as the first one).

With these changes, the input file looks like (the changes are mainly in the lines starting with three backticks ```` ``` ````):

````
---
title: "TestFile"
author: "Brian Hurler"
date: "12/15/2020"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{subfigure}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::include_graphics
library(knitr)
library(remotes)
library(lubridate)
# library(datavolley)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggalt)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(RGraphics)
library(scales)
library(patchwork)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggimage)
library(magick)
library(jpeg)
library(zoo)
library(readxl)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results = "asis", out.width= "900px", include=FALSE}
player_name <- c("Brian Hurley", "Justin Zhang", "Jon Fong", "Brian Hurley", "Justin Zhang", "Jon Fong", "Brian Hurley", "Justin Zhang", "Jon Fong")
matches <- data.frame(player_name)

scout_reception <- matches %>%
  group_by(player_name) %>%
  summarise(
    attempts = n())
```

```{=latex}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{minipage}[c][3.95in]{0.72\textwidth}
```

```{r}
kable(scout_reception)
```

```{=latex}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{-.5cm}%
\begin{minipage}[c][3.95in]{0.72\textwidth}
```

```{r}
kable(scout_reception)
```

```{=latex}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```
````

This file, when Knit (like WEB's weave) produces what appears to be the expected PDF output:

[image: output]